# Do you need to empty a 500 gal propane tank if the shutoff valve is leaking?

Tags: leak

I own my tank that came with my home purchase. My propane supplier said I should never shut off the main valve. How do I replace the valve if I do an upgrade to support new gas appliances? I don't have a shutoff inside the home for the main, just at each appliance.

Comment: You can not replace the tank valve util the tank is empty

Comment: Your title and the body of the post disagree about why you need to change it.

Answer (score 9):

Generally, folks that like continuing to live hire competent help with the appropriate equipment for rare jobs involving lots of flammable gas. If leaking, they do so without delay.

Presumably your propane supplier can (for a fee) stop by with a near-empty truck and offload the contents of your tank temporarily, if the valve needs to be replaced; they could probably also provide a main shutoff for the house at the same time.

Comment: Also note: you do _not_ bring large tanks in for refill. You get someone to come to them and refill them in place. (I know someone who started to make that mistake, then realized they were being stupid.)

Comment: How. In. The. World??? How would Joe Average homeowner even begin to attempt to transport a large tank like that, @keshlam???? (Rhetorical question, but... wow...)

Comment: They were thinking in terms of propane tanks for grills, and they had a pickup truck available, and they didn't realize just how heavy the tank was, and they jumped to conclusions. 2+2=4 is obvious only when you understand 2, 4,:+,  and =; the most dangerous part of not knowing is not knowing what you don't know.